# Why is the same program running differently on Windows than Mac

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I was running a piece of code on my mac and it was able to run as I wanted it to but when I ran the same exact thing on my windows PC the output of the program was totally different. It was a java swing window that would allow you to move a dot around the screen. On the mac it was able to work perfectly fine, but on my windows PC the dot leaves a trail of afterimages. Basically every time the panel is repainted the graphics are not being cleared. What should I do to fix this? I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling java on my PC but it hasn't changed the output of the program. If you need to take a look at the graphics code it is here: https://github.com/Nathaniel-github/NetworkingTrialClient in the GraphicsPanel class.

Here is my paint component:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            if (notConnectedToServer()) {

                g.drawString("Connecting to server...", 680, 400);

            } else if (serverConnection) {

                try {

                    int numberOfPlayers = dataIn.readInt();

                    fileWriter.write("Data received(Number of Players): " + numberOfPlayers);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i ++) {

                        int x = dataIn.readInt();
                        fileWriter.write("Data received(X coordinate), Iteration " + i + ": " + x);
                        int y = dataIn.readInt();
                        fileWriter.write("Data received(Y coordinate), Iteration " + i + ": " + y);

                        g.fillOval(x - 5, y - 5, 10, 10);

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {

                g.fillOval(player.getX() - 5, player.getY() - 5, 10, 10);

            }

        }
```

Comment: You should include a [mre] in your question, but here's a suggestion: put `super.paintComponent(g);` at the top of your overridden `paintComponent` method. That will paint over whatever was there before.

Comment: oh thank you so much ya it fixed it

Comment: Cool. I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override `paintComponent`, typically you want to start by calling the overridden `paintComponent` method, which will fill in the space, painting over whatever was there from the last paint.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // Draw your stuff
}
```